# Able to ping the system using IP but not able to access api

Tags: api, connection, timeout, port

My API is running on the Windows system. I'm calling API from another MAC system, but it's just getting a timeout.

I'm able to ping from Mac to Windows and vice versa, but API not working which is running a specific port.

Also, if I'll connect mobile Hotspots then I'm able to call API. But using WIFI router not able to connect.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 11. After I disabled windows defender, I'm able to access API from other systems